# Guix System Problem with GNOME Boxes

Tags: gnome, virtual-machine, gnu, guix, gnome-boxes

To build a virtual machine with GNOME Boxes, I have this problem:
"virtualization extensions are unavailable on your system. Check your
bios settings to enable them."

what's the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid this issue with GNOME Boxes, I had to configure Guix System to add my user account to the `libvirt` group and enable the `virtlog` and `libvirt` system services as below.

```
(operating-system
  ...
  (users (append (list (user-account
                         (name "me")
                         (comment "Me")
                         (group "users")
                         (supplementary-groups '("libvirt"))))))
  ...
  (services (append
              (list (service virtlog-service-type)
                    (service libvirt-service-type
                      (libvirt-configuration (unix-sock-group "libvirt"))))))
  ...
)
```

My user account is also a member of the `kvm` group so I can use `guix system vm`. This may also be required for GNOME Boxes - I haven't tested without it.

These tips were given to me by liberdiko on Guix IRC.

Comment: Thanks Ben, the problem is solved. More at https://issues.guix.gnu.org/44805

Comment: I confirm that adding `kvm` to `supplementary-groups` and rebooting (even after restarting `libvirtd` and `virtlogd`) was necessary too. Also, I added `virtualization` to `use-service-modules` declaration to make `guix system reconfigure` recognize those service types.

Answer (score -1):

go to your Computer BIOS and Enable VM !

Comment: The problem is here, it is active!